# Should retiree take insurance from employer or should he/she take from external insurance organization?

Tags: india, retirement, insurance, health-insurance

My dad is retired bank official in India. I want to know if he should go for health insurance provided by his employer or he should go for other insurance organizations, given say the cover is exactly the same? Is there any intrinsic feature of emplyer-provided health insurance which make it more preferrable or un-preferrable over external insurance?

I was contacted by one of the health insurance provider's agent and she said that employer-provided insurance does not have continuity benefit. If the contract of employer ends with the original insurance organization, then they may have to go for clean / new insurance.

Is there any general preference / advice in such scenario?

Comment: How does a retiree have an employer?

Comment: My dad served a bank for 30+ years and retired from the bank at the age of 55. The bank provides group policy for all retired personnel.